# Mapping POJO with Snakeyaml with underscore in the name

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I have the following configuration file where I am trying to map this yaml file into Java POJO Classes with Snakeyaml library.

```
consumers:
  - acls:
      - group: GRP-NAME-1
        tags:
          - CON-NAME
      - group: GRP-NAME-2
        tags:
          - CON-NAME-TAG
    oauth2_credentials:
      - client_id: CRD-NAME
        client_secret: xxxx
        name: CRD-NAME
        redirect_uris:
          - http://xyz
        tags:
          - CON-NAME-TAG
    username: CON-NAME
    tags:
      - CON-NAME-TAG
```

RootConfig.java

```
public class RootConfig {

    private List<Consumer> consumers;

    public List<Consumer> getConsumers() {
        return consumers;
    }

    public void setConsumers(List<Consumer> consumers) {
        this.consumers = consumers;
    }
}
```

Consumer.java:

```
public class Consumer {

    private List<Acl> acls;

    private List<Oauth2Credential> oauth2Credentials;

    private String username;

    private List<String> tags;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<Acl> getAcls() {
        return acls;
    }

    public void setAcls(List<Acl> acls) {
        this.acls = acls;
    }

    public List<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public List<Oauth2Credential> getOauth2Credentials() {
        return oauth2Credentials;
    }

    public void setOauth2Credentials(List<Oauth2Credential> oauth2Credentials) {
        this.oauth2Credentials = oauth2Credentials;
    }
}
```

Oauth2Credential.java:

```
public class Oauth2Credential {

    private String clientId;

    private String clientSecret;

    private String name;

    private List<String> redirectUris;

    private List<String> tags;

    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public String getClientSecret() {
        return clientSecret;
    }

    public void setClientSecret(String clientSecret) {
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getRedirectUris() {
        return redirectUris;
    }

    public void setRedirectUris(List<String> redirectUris) {
        this.redirectUris = redirectUris;
    }

    public List<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

Acl.java:

```
public class Acl {

    private String group;

    private List<String> tags;

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public List<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

ConfigLoader.java:

```
public class ConfigLoader {

    public RootConfig load(String file) {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(RootConfig.class));

        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(file);
        RootConfig rootConfig = yaml.load(inputStream);
        System.out.println(rootConfig);

        return rootConfig;
    }
}
```

Config loader is giving me following error:

```
Caused by: Cannot create property=oauth2_credentials for JavaBean=uk.gov.hmrc.deck.config.tool.modal.Consumer@1554909b
 in 'reader', line 9, column 5:
      - oauth2_credentials:
        ^
Unable to find property 'oauth2_credentials' on class: uk.gov.hmrc.deck.config.tool.modal.Consumer
 in 'reader', line 10, column 7:
          - client_id: CRD-MDTP-BREATHINGS ... 
          ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:291)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:172)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObjectNoCheck(BaseConstructor.java:230)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:220)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructSequenceStep2(BaseConstructor.java:391)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructSequence(BaseConstructor.java:375)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructSequence.construct(Constructor.java:543)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObjectNoCheck(BaseConstructor.java:230)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:220)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.newInstance(Constructor.java:306)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:268)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Unable to find property 'oauth2_credentials' on class: uk.gov.hmrc.deck.config.tool.modal.Consumer
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:148)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.getProperty(Constructor.java:310)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:231)
    ... 20 more
```

If I remove *oauth2_credentials* element, it seems to be working fine. I believe the underscore in the name is causing this issue.
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `@YamlProperty(key = "oauth2_credentials")` as follows:

```java
public class Consumer {

    private List<Acl> acls;

    @YamlProperty(key = "oauth2_credentials")
    private List<Oauth2Credential> oauth2Credentials;

    private String username;

    private List<String> tags;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<Acl> getAcls() {
        return acls;
    }

    public void setAcls(List<Acl> acls) {
        this.acls = acls;
    }

    public List<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public List<Oauth2Credential> getOauth2Credentials() {
        return oauth2Credentials;
    }

    public void setOauth2Credentials(List<Oauth2Credential> oauth2Credentials) {
        this.oauth2Credentials = oauth2Credentials;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you must use `AnnotationAwareConstructor` when parsing:

```java
public class ConfigLoader {

    public RootConfig load(String file) {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new AnnotationAwareConstructor(RootConfig.class));

        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(file);
        RootConfig rootConfig = yaml.load(inputStream);
        System.out.println(rootConfig);

        return rootConfig;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have imported 'snakeyaml-anno', and added '@YamlProperty(key = "oauth2_credentials")'. I am still having the same error!

Comment: Which SnakeYaml are you using? Additionally, you need to use `Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new AnnotationAwareConstructor(RootConfig.class));`. Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: @adesai, I meant "Which SnakeYaml" version are you using?". I missed the "version" word :D